# Seleccionar mediante array de un json DataType de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla donde cuyas columnas son:

`id | name | surname | jobs`

La columna jobs es un datatype de json, donde se almacenara un array de todo los trabajos que realizo la persona. Ejemplo de json:

```
{
   "jobs": ["programador", "camarero", "ayudante de ventas"]
}
```

Y quisiera saber cual seria la sintaxis del **SQL** para seleccionar las personas mediante los trabajos dentro del array del json.

**Por ejemplo: Seleccionar toda las personas que trabajaron como camarero**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede conseguirse con una combinación de [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) y [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search);

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int, coljson JSON);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES 
(1,'{"jobs": ["programador", "camarero", "ayudante de ventas"]}'),
(2,'{"jobs": ["programador", "camarero", "profesor"]}'),
(3,'{"jobs": ["programador", "profesor"]}');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(coljson, '$.jobs') AS JOBS FROM t1
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(coljson, '$.jobs'), 'one','camarero') IS NOT NULL;
```

**Resultado:**

```
| id  | JOBS                                              |
| --- | ------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | ["programador", "camarero", "ayudante de ventas"] |
| 2   | ["programador", "camarero", "profesor"]           |
```

---

- [Ver demo en DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qZVXU1iN89wDWFeFHB7Tvc/0)
- [Functions That Search JSON Values :: MySQL Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

Comment: Dichas funciones están disponibles desde `MySQL 5.7`

Comment: ¿El segundo parametro de JSON_SEARCH() 'one' que quiere decir?

Comment: @ABC con one la búsqueda termina tras el primer match con el elemento buscado, en este caso como sólo se quiere saber si el elemento "camarero" está o no  se usa para que si lo encuentra no continúe buscando en el resto del array.